# Как поменять цвет, при наведение на элемент что находится ниже?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const changeColor = document.querySelector('.watch__name')

function changeItem() {
  changeColor.style.color = '#4338CA';
}

function rechangeItem() {
  changeColor.style.color = '#000';
}
```

```html
<div class="watch__anceta">
  <div class="watch__times">
    <span class="time__first">part-time</span>
    <span class="time__second">full-time</span>
  </div>
  <img src="img/third/third2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:20px;" alt="1">
  <h4 class="watch__name">Татьяна Петрова</h4>
  <h5 class="watch__profession">QA-тестировщик </h5>
  <div class="watch__time-work">Опыт: более 5 лет</div>
  <div class="watch__price">Зарплата: от 1500 €</div>
  <a href="#" class="third-hover" onmouseover="changeItem()" onmouseout="rechangeItem()">Посмотреть справку</a>
</div>
<div class="watch__anceta">
  <div class="watch__times">
    <span class="time__first">part-time</span>
    <span class="time__second">full-time</span>
  </div>
  <img src="img/third/third3.jpg" style="margin-bottom:20px;" alt="1">
  <h4 class="watch__name">Сергей Васильев</h4>
  <h5 class="watch__profession">QA-тестировщик </h5>
  <div class="watch__time-work">Опыт: более 5 лет</div>
  <div class="watch__price">Зарплата: от 1000 €</div>
  <a href="#" class="third-hover" onmouseover="changeItem()" onmouseout="rechangeItem()">Посмотреть справку</a>
</div>
```

> Мне нужно чтобы при наведение на тег a, менялся цвет тега h4. Проблема в том, что при наведении меняется цвет только у первого h4 тега,но применяя SelectorAll, тогда у всех одновременно тегов h4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1** использовать `:has` - https://caniuse.com/css-has

```css
.watch__name:has(~.third-hover:hover) {
  color: #4338CA;
}
```

```html
<div class="watch__anceta">
  <div class="watch__times">
    <span class="time__first">part-time</span>
    <span class="time__second">full-time</span>
  </div>
  <img src="img/third/third2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:20px;" alt="1">
  <h4 class="watch__name">Татьяна Петрова</h4>
  <h5 class="watch__profession">QA-тестировщик </h5>
  <div class="watch__time-work">Опыт: более 5 лет</div>
  <div class="watch__price">Зарплата: от 1500 €</div>
  <a href="#" class="third-hover">Посмотреть справку</a>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2**

```js
const watchLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.third-hover')

watchLinks.forEach(link => {
  const name = link.closest('.watch__anceta').querySelector('.watch__name');

  link.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    name.style.color = '#4338CA';
  })

  link.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    name.style.color = '#000';
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="watch__anceta">
  <div class="watch__times">
    <span class="time__first">part-time</span>
    <span class="time__second">full-time</span>
  </div>
  <img src="img/third/third2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:20px;" alt="1">
  <h4 class="watch__name">Татьяна Петрова</h4>
  <h5 class="watch__profession">QA-тестировщик </h5>
  <div class="watch__time-work">Опыт: более 5 лет</div>
  <div class="watch__price">Зарплата: от 1500 €</div>
  <a href="#" class="third-hover">Посмотреть справку</a>
</div>
<div class="watch__anceta">
  <div class="watch__times">
    <span class="time__first">part-time</span>
    <span class="time__second">full-time</span>
  </div>
  <img src="img/third/third3.jpg" style="margin-bottom:20px;" alt="1">
  <h4 class="watch__name">Сергей Васильев</h4>
  <h5 class="watch__profession">QA-тестировщик </h5>
  <div class="watch__time-work">Опыт: более 5 лет</div>
  <div class="watch__price">Зарплата: от 1000 €</div>
  <a href="#" class="third-hover">Посмотреть справку</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)